# Change cursor to hourglass/wait/busy cursor and back in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, mouse-cursor

I spawn a process that performs a lengthy operation, and I'd like to give visual feedback that something is happening, so I want to change the cursor to busy and restore it when I receive the `QProcess::finished` signal.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Qsiris solution is "widget wide". If you want to change cursor for your whole application then use

```
QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
```

and

```
QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
```

**Note:** As @Ehsan Khodarahmi pointed out, the cursor will NOT change until triggering next QT event or calling QApplication::processEvents() manually.

Comment: don't forgive that the cursor will NOT change until triggering next QT event or calling `QApplication::processEvents()` manually

Comment: @EhsanKhodarahmi:  I think you meant "don't forget", but after an hour of wrestling with that very issue, "don't forgive" works well, too.  Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Note that UI will not be blocked this way, and you may use `setEnabled(false)` if your app is QWidget-based.

Comment: Details: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#CursorShape-enum

Answer (score 28):

Use this to set the cursor to wait when the process begins:

```
this->setCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
```

And this to restore the cursor back to normal (put this in the slot for QProcess::finished)

```
this->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
```

Comment: To restore the cursor, better use `unsetCursor()`. It will inherit the parent cursor, which was the behavior prior to explicitly setting one: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#cursor-prop