# Qt how to make a button responsive when the slot connected to its clicked() signal is running?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I have a button with a slot connected to its clicked() signal.

The slot is a time consuming task and take many seconds.

When trying to re-click the button before the slot ends, I can't.

How to make the button responsive when running the slot connected to its clicked() signal?

Comment: Use threads and run the task in a separate thread?

Comment: You could start another thread in the slot and then not wait for the task. Another "simple" solution is display a wait cursor so people see there is activity. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495283/change-cursor-to-hourglass-wait-busy-cursor-and-back-in-qt but this may be not what you are trying to do

Comment: Never run time consuming tasks on the main UI thread, whether in response to a signal or otherwise. That freezes your whole UI.

Comment: Is using threads the only solution?

Comment: Or indicating the User that the GUI is blocked. But if you want the GUI to be responsive. Yes

Comment: OK, Thanks. Could anyone write an answer so that I can tick and upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything running in the GUI must not block nor take much time to finish. Don't do long-running things in the GUI thread. That will fix your problem.

Now you may ask: so how do I do long-running things, then? You do them in other threads, but that doesn't imply having to ever see an instance of a `QThread`, though.

You have to isolate the data and the operations on it. Suppose we have a following class:

```
class MyData {
public:
    MyData() {}
    /// Loads and pre-processes the data
    bool load(const QString & file) { QThread::sleep(5); return true; }
    /// Transforms the data
    void transform() { QThread::sleep(2); }
};

using MyDataPtr = std::shared_ptr<MyData>;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyDataPtr)

int main(...) { qRegisterMetaType<MyDataPtr>(); ... }
```

To make it most general, we assume that `MyData` is expensive to copy and move.

If the operation is of a "generate new data" kind, say like reading a file, processing the data and building up a data structure, you can instantiate the data in a worker thread and pass it to the GUI thread:

```
class GuiClass : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    MyDataPtr data;
    Q_SIGNAL void hasData(const MyDataPtr &);
public:
    GuiClass() {
        connect(this, &GuiClass::hasData,
                this, [this](const MyDataPtr & newData){ data = newData; });
    }
    Q_SLOT void makeData(const QString & file) {
        QtConcurrent::run([=]{
            auto data = std::make_shared<MyData>();
            if (data->load(file))
                emit hasData(data);
        });
    }
```

If you need to transform the data already in place, some common approaches are:

1. Copy the data, transform it in a worker thread, then swap it out after the transformation.

   ```
       Q_SLOT void transformData1() {
           MyDataPtr copy = std::make_shared<MyData>(*data);
           QtConcurrent::run([=]{
               copy->transform();
               emit hasData(copy);
           });
       }
   ```
2. Temporarily remove the data, transform it, then put it back. The UI will have to cope with missing data, e.g. by showing a "busy" indicator when `data` is null.

   ```
      Q_SLOT void transformData2() {
           MyDataPtr data = this->data;
           this->data.reset();
           QtConcurrent::run([=]{
               data->transform();
               emit hasData(data);
           });
       }
   ```

If `MyData` were easily movable, and the default value had a meaning of "null"/"empty", you could hold on to it by value instead:

```
class GuiClassVal : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    MyData data;
    struct DataEvent : public QEvent {
        static const QEvent::Type type;
        MyData data;
        DataEvent(const MyData & data) : QEvent{type}, data{data} {}
        DataEvent(MyData && data) : QEvent{type}, data{std::move(data)} {}
    };
    /// This method is thread-safe.
    void setData(MyData && data) {
        QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new DataEvent{std::move(data)});
    }
    /// This method is thread-safe.
    void setData(const MyData & data) {
        QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new DataEvent{data});
    }
    bool event(QEvent *event) override {
        if (event->type() == DataEvent::type) {
            data.~MyData();
            new (&data) MyData{std::move(static_cast<DataEvent*>(event)->data)};
            return true;
        }
        return QWidget::event(event);
    }
    void transformInEvent(DataEvent * ev){
        ev->data.transform();
        QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, ev);
    };
public:
    Q_SLOT void makeData(const QString & file) {
        QtConcurrent::run([=]{
            MyData data;
            if (data.load(file)) setData(std::move(data));
        });
    }
    Q_SLOT void transformData1() {
        QtConcurrent::run(this, &GuiClassVal::transformInEvent, new DataEvent{data});
    }
    Q_SLOT void transformData2() {
        QtConcurrent::run(this, &GuiClassVal::transformInEvent, new DataEvent{std::move(data)});
    }
};
const QEvent::Type GuiClassVal::DataEvent::type = (QEvent::Type)QEvent::registerEventType();
```

The event-based magic sauce can of course be factored out.

Comment: Very complete answer, +1. I should put this as the answer to be fair.

Answer (score 4):

You have two high-level choices:

- spawn the time-consuming choices into a thread: the simplest way is to use `QtConcurrent::run()`, and on the GUI side you'll need to worry about handling all the GUI events appropriately while your operation executes.
- within your time-consuming code, call `QApplication::processEvents()` often enough that the GUI remains responsive (e.g., on the inside of a loop):  this won't work if the time-consuming operation is 3rd party code you can't break out of, and you'll still need to work out how to handle GUI operations while you've got your long-running task executing.

You'll find that the first choice is by far the consensus better choice over the second, FWIW.

Comment: Another problem with `QApplication::processEvents()` is that you may now have to deal with reentrancy. E.g. if you call it from a slot and the button is clicked again, your slot will be called again, recursively, from within itself. Chances are, it doesn't expect that and would not work right.